# Cómo imprimo el dato de un arreglo en Json despues de hacer la búsqueda por codigo?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, json

tengo este codigo el cual busca en una base .json si el agente esta autorizado o no, en el .json solo estan los autorizados, así que si no lo encuentra, salta el mensaje correspondiente. Mi consulta es, cómo hago para despues de la búsqueda, me aparesca el nombre del agente tambien, u otros datos que quiera que aparezcan. Gracias.

Codigo .html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Busqueda</title>
<link rel="icon" href="/logot.ico">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<style>

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nosifer');

.noautorizado{
    color: #eb2f06;

}

.autorizado{
    color: #3498db;

}

.buscaragente{
    font-family: 'Nosifer', cursive;
}

</style>

<body>

<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>

<center><h1 class="buscaragente">Buscar Agente</h1>

<br>
<br>

<input type="text" placeholder="Ingresa DNI" onkeyup="ajax_get_json(this.value)"/></center>

<br>

<center><div id="info" ></div></center>

<script>

function ajax_get_json(usuarioIngresado){

var resultado = document.getElementById("info");
var xmlhttp;

if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
}else{
    xmlhttp = ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

if (usuarioIngresado.length === 0){
resultado.innerHTML = "";
}
else{
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200){
var datos = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);

        var x = encontrarPersona(datos, usuarioIngresado);
        var mensaje = (x === true) ?    "<span class= 'autorizado'>Si está autorizado</span>" : 
                                        "<span class= 'noautorizado'>No está autorizado</span>";                                
        resultado.innerHTML = mensaje;
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", "datos1.json", true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
}

function encontrarPersona(objetoJSON, usuario){

var arreglo = [];

for (var i in objetoJSON) {
    var persona = objetoJSON[i];
    arreglo.push(persona.nombre);
}


return arreglo.indexOf(usuario) > -1;

}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Codigo .json

```
[

{
    "nombre" : "88888888",
    "agente" : "Giu Massinger Bimbo One"
}

]
```

Comment: ¿El JSON es estático? Es decir, ¿es un fichero JSON que siempre tiene los mismos valores?

Comment: Así es, tendrá los mismos valores.
Al buscar con el codigo, y me aparesca si esta autorizado o no, quiero que tambien me salga el nombre del agente

Comment: Como comentario, el código es bastante ineficiente. Cada vez que se pulsa una tecla se carga el JSON, se procesa completo y se busca en él. Sólo haría falta cargar y procesar el JSON una vez.

Comment: Intenté hacer que la búqueda sea en tiempo real, el código hace lo que yo quiero, quiza no fue la mejor forma, pero funciona. Pero deseo algo más, que me aparesca el nombre del codigo buscado, Noce como imprimirlo en pantalla tambien, al momento de hacer la busqueda.

Comment: Eso es lo que hace mi respuesta: en lugar de devolver un verdadero/falso, devuelve el objeto que cumple con las condiciones dadas, entonces puedes usar cualquier dato que haya dentro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo tienes básicamente hecho, lo que podrías hacer es, en lugar de devolver un booleano con verdadero o falso, devolver un array con las coincidencias en sí. Entonces en lugar de comprobar si el valor es verdadero o falso, lo que harías es comprobar la longitud del array: si es mayor que 0, se encontraron coincidencias (que estarán en el array); si el tamaño es 0, es que no hubo coincidencias.

Para eso tienes que cambiar la función `encontrarPersona` a algo como esto:

```
function encontrarPersona(objetoJSON, usuario){

  var arreglo = [];

  for (var i in objetoJSON) {
    var persona = objetoJSON[i];
    // sólo agregamos al array si el nombre coincide (y agregamos todo)
    if (persona.nombre == usuario) arreglo.push(persona);
  }

  // devolvemos el array
  return arreglo;
}
```

Y ahora en la función que lee los datos desde AJAX y llama a `encontrarPersona` sólo tienes que cambiarla un poco en esta parte:

```
    var x = encontrarPersona(datos, usuarioIngresado);
    // compruebas la longitud del array en lugar de true o false
    var mensaje = (x.length > 0) ? "<span class= 'autorizado'>Si está autorizado</span>" :
                                   "<span class= 'noautorizado'>No está autorizado</span>";
    resultado.innerHTML = mensaje;
```

Por último, puedes cambiar el código de arriba para añadir los datos del usuario si está autorizado. En el mismo snippet de arriba, añade los datos que quieras. Por ejemplo:

```
    var x = encontrarPersona(datos, usuarioIngresado);
    // compruebas la longitud del array en lugar de true o false
    var mensaje = (x.length > 0) ? "<span class= 'autorizado'>Si está autorizado</span>" :
                                   "<span class= 'noautorizado'>No está autorizado</span>";
    for (var numUsuarios = 0; numUsuarios < x.length; numUsuarios++) {
      mensaje += "<span>Nombre: " + x[numUsuarios].nombre + ". " +
                 "Agente: " + x[numUsuarios].agente + "</span>";
    }
    resultado.innerHTML = mensaje
```

> Nota: he modificado la función `ajax_get_json` para que en lugar de cargar el JSON con AJAX lo que haga sea cargarlo desde una variable. Es para que puedas ver el ejemplo corriendo sin problemas en este sitio (las llamadas AJAX se bloquean).

```js
var datosOnline = [{
    "nombre": "88888888",
    "agente": "William Shakespeare"
  },
  {
    "nombre": "77777777",
    "agente": "Miguel de Cervantes"
  }
];

function ajax_get_json(usuarioIngresado) {

  var resultado = document.getElementById("info");

  if (usuarioIngresado.length === 0) {
    resultado.innerHTML = "";
  } else {
    var datos = datosOnline;

    var x = encontrarPersona(datos, usuarioIngresado);

    // compruebas la longitud del array en lugar de true o false
    var mensaje = (x.length > 0) ? "<span class= 'autorizado'>Si está autorizado</span>" :
      "<span class= 'noautorizado'>No está autorizado</span>";
    for (var numUsuarios = 0; numUsuarios < x.length; numUsuarios++) {
      mensaje += "<span>Nombre: " + x[numUsuarios].nombre + ". " +
        "Agente: " + x[numUsuarios].agente + "</span>";
    }
    resultado.innerHTML = mensaje
  }
  /*var xmlhttp;

  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {
    xmlhttp = ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }

  if (usuarioIngresado.length === 0) {
    resultado.innerHTML = "";
  } else {
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200) {
        var datos = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);

        var x = encontrarPersona(datos, usuarioIngresado);
        // compruebas la longitud del array en lugar de true o false
        var mensaje = (x.length > 0) ? "<span class= 'autorizado'>Si está autorizado</span>" :
          "<span class= 'noautorizado'>No está autorizado</span>";
        for (var numUsuarios = 0; numUsuarios < x.length; numUsuarios++) {
          mensaje += "<span>Nombre: " + x[numUsuarios].nombre + ". " +
            "Agente: " + x[numUsuarios].agente + "</span>";
        }
        resultado.innerHTML = mensaje
      }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "datos1.json", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
  }
  */
}

function encontrarPersona(objetoJSON, usuario) {

  var arreglo = [];

  for (var i in objetoJSON) {
    var persona = objetoJSON[i];
    // sólo agregamos al array si el nombre coincide (y agregamos todo)
    if (persona.nombre == usuario) arreglo.push(persona);
  }

  // devolvemos el array
  return arreglo;
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nosifer');
.noautorizado {
  color: #eb2f06;
}

.autorizado {
  color: #3498db;
}

.buscaragente {
  font-family: 'Nosifer', cursive;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<center>
  <h1 class="buscaragente">Buscar Agente</h1>
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Ingresa DNI" onkeyup="ajax_get_json(this.value)" />
</center>

<br>

<center>
  <div id="info"></div>
</center>
```

---

Y no relacionado con el problema en sí, aunque recomendado, deberías cambiar el HTML porque no es válido. Alguno de los problemas que presenta:

- Usas etiquetas que se consideran obsoletas (p.e. `center`)
- Usas `br` para crear separación entre elementos, eso es una mala idea porque la separación que crean va a depender del tamaño de letra que tenga cada usuario, deberías definir esa separación entre elementos en CSS en lugar de inundar el código con muchos `br`.
- La etiqueta `style` debe ir en el `head` o en el `body` pero no fuera de ellos.
- Pones JavaScript inline: aunque esto es válido, no es algo recomendado. Sería mejor separar HTML (vista) del JavaScript (controlador).

Aparte de eso, y como ponía en un comentario a la pregunta, el código es poco eficiente porque cada vez que se pulsa una tecla se va a realizar una llamada para obtener el JSON, procesarlo e intentar comprobar los valores... pero según tu comentario el JSON siempre va a ser el mismo.

Si cambiara con cada petición, aunque no tan ineficiente, también presentaría problemas, por ejemplo: se realiza la petición con cada tecla pulsada sin ninguna espera, puede darse el caso que realices múltiples llamadas pero sólo te interese la última (aparte de que al no estar ordenadas, podría ocurrir que una petición anterior sobreescriba los resultados de una petición posterior).

Comment: Excelente..!
La experiencia mi amigo, hace no mucho yo recién acabo de adentrarme en todo esto.
Gracias, tu código me ayudó muchísimo..!

Comment: Hola @Li0n11. Si esta respuesta ayudó a solucionar tu problema, por favor considerá aceptarla haciendo click en el ✓ a la izquierda de la misma, debajo de las flechas de votación.

Comment: Espero no abusar, jejeje
...pero estoy intentando validar en que arreglo se encuentra el dato para que me salte el mensaje si está autorizado o no, cómo valido en qué arreglo está. Ayuda porfaaa.. :)

var usuariosAutorizados = [
 {"nombre": "88888888", "agente": "MARCK IBRAIMOVICH", "user": "P67312"},
   {"nombre": "77777777", "agente": "Miguel de Cervantes Saavedra", "user": "L97634"}
];

var usuariosNoAutorizados = [
 {"nombre": "99999999", "agente": "Elon Muss Bodytech", "user": "S35678"},
   {"nombre": "66666666", "agente": "Pablo Villanueva Melcocha", "user": "G15948"}
];

Answer (score 0):

espero ayudar.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Busqueda</title>
  <link rel="icon" href="/logot.ico">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<style>
  @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nosifer');
  .noautorizado {
    color: #eb2f06;
  }
  
  .autorizado {
    color: #3498db;
  }
  
  .buscaragente {
    font-family: 'Nosifer', cursive;
  }
</style>

<body>

  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>

  <center>
    <h1 class="buscaragente">Buscar Agente</h1>

    <br>
    <br>

    <input type="text" placeholder="Ingresa DNI" onkeyup="ajax_get_json(this.value)" /></center>

  <br>

  <center>
    <div id="info"></div>
  </center>

  <script>
    function ajax_get_json(usuarioIngresado) {

      var resultado = document.getElementById("info");
      var xmlhttp;

      if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      } else {
        xmlhttp = ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }

      if (usuarioIngresado.length === 0) {
        resultado.innerHTML = "";
      } else {
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200) {
            var datos = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);

            var user = datos.filter(function(e) {
              return e.nombre === usuarioIngresado;
            })

            var mensaje = (user.length > 0) ?
              `<span class= 'autorizado'>Si está autorizado: ${user[0].nombre}, ${user[0].agente}</span>` :
              `<span class= 'noautorizado'>No está autorizado</span>`;
            resultado.innerHTML = mensaje;
          }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "datos1.json", true);
        xmlhttp.send();
      }
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Me aparece lo que añadiste como texto al ejecutar la pagina, igualmente muchas gracias

Comment: Hola Lewis, las respuestas que son sólo código se consideran de baja calidad. Trata de añadir una descripción de los cambios que realizaste en el código y cómo/por qué solucionarían el problema expuesto en la pregunta. Lee [answer] para más información.